# Pandas .apply function and assign indexed value of function return

Tags: python, pandas, mapbox, geocoding

I have a pandas DataFrame with some addresses that I am trying to geocode. The geocoding function returns a list of Lat, Long. I'd like to assign the `Lat` and `Long` to columns in Pandas DataFrame separately.

Here's the code.

```
import geocoder
token = MAPBOX_KEY

def get_geocodes(address):

    g = geocoder.mapbox(address, key=token)
    geojson = g.json
    address = geojson["address"]

    coords = [geojson['lat'], geojson['lng']]

    Lat = coords[0]
    Long = coords[1]

    return (Lat, Long)

# DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3],
               'Addr': ['320 E Willeta Phoenix AZ 85004',
                        '6811 East Main Street Scottsdale AZ 85251',
                        '20446-20456 Saticoy Street Los Angeles CA 91306'],
               'Lat': [1,1,1],
               'Long': [1,1,1]
              })


# Apply lat, long to Pandas DataFrame

df['Lat'] = df.apply(lambda x : get_geocodes(x['Addr']), axis=1)
df['Long'] = df.apply(lambda x : get_geocodes(x['Addr']), axis=1)
```

How do I access the values of the list and assign to Pandas DataFrame Lat and Long columns? I'd prefer to not modify the function as it is used in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(x['Addr'].apply(get_geocodes), columns=['Lat', 'Long'])
df = pd.concat([df, tmp_df], axis=1)
```

Or, if you want to expand the two columns, you can pass [`result_type='expand'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to `DataFrame.apply`:

```
df[['Lat', 'Long']] = df.apply(lambda x: get_geocodes(x['Addr']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Comment: Thx. This works, however, I was wondering if there is a way to slice the list returned by the function and assign that to the pandas column.

Comment: You mean, you want your `lambda x : get_geocodes(x['Addr'])` to be expanded into two columns, instead of just returning one column containing tuples?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Expand the tuple into two columns.

Comment: Yep, that can be done to. Give me a sec

Comment: @kms check the answer now. :)

Comment: could you add a bit of explanation?

Comment: Yes, please give me a minute or two. :)

Comment: Sorry, I left some debugging stuff in there. Check the answer now. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the dataframe, a comprehension might be faster:

```
df['Lat'], df['Long'] = zip(*(get_geocodes(i) for i in df['Addr']))
```

This idiom slices the return values into two lists, as requested.

You should check what works better for you.

**Extra**

inside `get_geocodes`, you can simplify the last 4 lines of code by:

```
return (geojson['lat'], geojson['lng'])
```